ABCD Matrix for an aspheric lens
I'm familiar with the ABCD matrices for a reflecting and refracting surface with a given radius of curvature. I was wondering if we are given an aspheric lens described by qcons, for the paraxial analysis of this lens and for the computation of its ABCD matrix, what form is used?
My first thought is to ignore the aspheric parts of the lens and just use the base curvature with the ABCD matrix for a refracting sphere, but I am not sure if that's how Zemax and commercial software treat the problem? Are there dedicated ABCD matrices for more complex optical elements or does the paraxial approximation inherent in ABCD matrices dictate that we only consider the spherical part?

ABCD matrices are only applicable for the paraxial region, where rays travel close to the optical axis.  The function of an asphere is that the description of rays traveling through them are not just simple scaling of the paraxial rays.
Zemax and similar software trace rays through aspheres by propagating single rays, one at a time. Iteration is required in order to find the point of the ray intersection with the asphere surface.  For a system governed by ABCD matrices, different rays can just be linear superpositions of other rays, but that is not the case for aspheric systems.
